# Storing a binary tree in a file

Tags: java, data-structures, preorder

So I am trying store a binary tree in a file. I am doing this to store it in the file.

```
public String[] getTree() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    String[] str;
    preOrder(root, list);
    str = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    return str;
}

private void preOrder(Node current, ArrayList list) {
    if (current == null) {
        list.add("&");
        return;
    }
    list.add(current.getValue());
    preOrder(current.getLeft(), list);
    preOrder(current.getRight(), list);
}
```

Basically every null node I represent as an &, and each node is separated by a line break. With this array I send it to file. Now when the program starts up again it reads this file and puts it back in the array. However I am having issues wrapping my head around the process for this and nothing that I read seems to help. This is the current algorithm I am trying, however it does not work for large trees.

```
private void makeBinaryTree(String[] in) {
    root = new Node(in[0]);
    Node current = root;
    boolean left = true;
    for(int i = 1; i < in.length; i++){
        if(!in[i].equals("&")){
            if(left){
                Node toAdd = new Node(in[i]);
                toAdd.setParent(current);
                current.setLeft(toAdd);
                current = toAdd;
            }else{
                Node toAdd = new Node(in[i]);
                toAdd.setParent(current);
                current.setRight(toAdd);
                current = toAdd;
                left = true;
            }

/*            }else if(left && in[i].equals("&")){
                  left = false;
          */}else if(!left && in[i].equals("&")){
            left = false;
            current = current.getParent();
            current = current.getParent();
        }else if(i+1 >= in.length){
        }else if(in[i].equals("&") && in[i+1].equals("&")){
            current = current.getParent();
            left = (!left);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize an store your object(tree). Read this:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java

But storing and loading big trees like that is not a good idea.